# Cryptographic Licensing Module not working from website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, digital-signature

We have developed a small method that pulls a cryptographic key from a signed xml document and then checks the signature using the SignedXml.CheckSignature method.

When run from a command line app the key validates properly. However as soon as I call it from a web app it stops working. Anybody know what could be happening?:

```
    // Verify the signature of an XML file against an asymmetric 
    // algorithm and return the result.XmlDocument Doc, RSA Key
    public static Boolean VerifyLicenceFile(string xmlLicFilePathArg)
    {
        bool isVerified = false;

        try
        {

            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = containerName;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            // Create a new XML document.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlLicFilePathArg);


            // Check arguments.
            if (xmlDoc == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Doc");
            if (rsaKey == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Key");

            // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
            // the XML document class.
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

            // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
            // XmlNodeList object.
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            // Throw an exception if no signature was found.
            if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
            }

            // This example only supports one signature for
            // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception 
            // if more than one signature was found.
            if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
            }

            // Load the first <signature> node.  
            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

            // Check the signature and return the result.
            isVerified = signedXml.CheckSignature(rsaKey);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }

        return isVerified;

    }
```

Comment: OK, what is the error? What does 'stops working' mean? Where does pathArgs come from?

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been more explicit. 'Stops working' means that the isVerified value is just false. There is no error and I cant see any difference in what is happening. I cant actually step into any of the c# classes (obviously) so not sure. The pathArg is the path to a license file which definetly exists and definitely works when called from a command line....

Comment: Both Consaole and ASP apps run on the same PC?

Comment: yep, running them all from the same machine.... :0(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the webserver runs as another user than the command-line tool. Unless you use the [`CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspproviderflags.aspx) the `CspParameters` will default to using the user key-store. `RsaCryptoServiceProvider` will silently generate a new key if the specified key-container does not exist, so the result is that your code uses a different key to verify when running in the web-server than when running from the the command-line.

Comment: @Pete2k: You need to make sure that the key that signs the data is the same as the one that verifies. To be completely sure, you might want to log rsaKey.ToXmlString(false). Unless the strings are identical when signing and verifying you are not using the same key.

Comment: RASMUS YOU ACTUALLY GOT ME THE ANSWER HERE :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715463/is-it-possible-to-sign-an-xml-document-without-having-to-use-keycontainername