# Is it possible to sign an xml document without having to use KeyContainerName?

Tags: c#, licensing, cryptography, signedxml

I want to create 2 really simple dlls:

1) that will sign an xml document
2) that will check that the xml document hasnt been modified.

I tried using the RSACryptoServiceProvider and a key container. But when I move to a different machine this does not work as the key is being stored in the machine.

I want to store the key in the dlls im creating (I know this is not reccomended) but I just cannot work out how to write some code to simply sign an xml document and then verify that it hasn't been changed.

So do I need to use symmetric key to do what I want is this possible?

Pete

Comment: Signing is performed using keypairs (public and private key). You sign using private key, which remains secret, and others verify signature using public key, which is usually distributed with your document (in XMLDSig it's included into the signature). Symmetric key is not used in signing. As for your question regarding key containers - unfortunately I don't know how to do this with .NET Framework classes - our SecureBlackbox product offers complete XML signing framework without such hassles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already mention the problems with storing the private key in the dll, so I won't repeat that.

Do this:

On your own machine run this code:

```
var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
string publicKey = key.ToXmlString(false);
string privateKey = key.ToXmlString(true);
Console.WriteLine(publicKey);
Console.WriteLine(privateKey);
```

this outputs two (long) lines. Copy those into your code:

Sign:

```
var privateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
privateKey.FromXmlString(/* insert the private-key XML string here */ );
privateKey.SignData(/*...*/);
```

Verify:

```
var publicKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
publicKey.FromXmlString(/* insert the public-key XML string here */ );
publicKey.VerifyData(/*...*/);
```

Comment: Hi Rasmus thanks for the advice this is actually correct I have implemented. I didnt realise you could export and split the keys. This is exactly what i needed to do the machine key store isnt any good for licenses we are sending out.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about to verify that your xml document hasn't been modified a simple [MD5 checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) (or any other good hashing algorithm) would be easier to implement and is what you need. It would be also verifyable on different machines.